# How to create Java project with classname.java instead of App.java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm learning java and I I have tried using Eclipse, IDEA and when I create a new project called say "iSuck", they would generate a file called iSuck.java inside src folder. When I switched to vsCode and tried their basic project generator, yeah the project folder is called "iSuck" but the src file is always App.java. Is there a way to set up vsCode so that projects behave like Eclipse/IDEA or just running App.java is better?

Comment: I'm not a VSC user, but can't you just rename the class?

Comment: yeah I can but then I'd be renaming the java file, the class name inside the java file and the src folder too, which might just be minor inconvenience for simple projects I'm doing but it may be different from larger ones. So I'm looking for a way to change it now just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find where to create a `new` java file inside your IDE program.

Normally, when you create a new file the program will prompts a box for you fill with the name of this new file then you can just create a file with the name you want.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't matter what the class and file name is. It makes absolutely no difference.